# What is the element being used here?

Tags: website-design, highlights

[image]

I cant inspect element and find out, how they have implemented it. It's not simple highlight though, it has this *glassy* , feel to it .

Edit : not glassy anymore

Comment: Looks like a "simple highlight" to me.  I, personally, get no connotation of "glossy" from your image. However, you can use a *gradient* rather than a flat color.

Comment: 1) i said glAss @Scott

Comment: 2) idk check here please https://www.vox.com/energy-and-environment/2018/10/29/18037154/electric-vehicles-trump-epa-fuel-economy-standards-moot @Scott

Comment: Glassy, glossy. it's neither to me. it's just a yellow background on a span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

## HTML

```
<p>This is a <span><b>marker highlight</b></span> text</p>
```

## CSS

```
p{
font-size:30px;
text-align:center;
font-family: Gotham;
font-style:italic;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

span{
padding:0 6px;
background: yellow;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

span b{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/danielillo/full/xyNmmJ)

Answer (score 3):

I found the website you are referring to and used the inspector to select a header which has the yellow highlight:

[image]

It seems to be just a background color.

I don't see anything "glassy" about this.

Comment: thank you that's what people are saying, found out it was just the gray contrast